# Compatible gas control valve for water heater

Tags: plumbing, water-heater

I have a reliance 640GORT 300 (approx 6 years old) water heater with a Honeywell WV88040B1042 gas control valve. The pilot light and status light on the gas control valve are off and I have followed the lighting instructions to no avail.

I had someone come out and recommend replacing the control valve, but I am wondering if there is a non-digital control valve that would be compatible with the existing water heater.

Also, if anyone has a suggestion as to another possible problem I'd be happy to hear it.  Still trying to decide whether to repair or get a new water heater.

Comment: Is gas reaching the valve to begin with?

Comment: I believe so?  Our basement had a lot of water in it due to a recent storm and since then it hasn't been working.

Comment: Yeah -- a flooded gas valve definitely needs to be replaced

Comment: Okay, that's helpful.  Would I be able to replace a digital valve like this (http://www.searspartsdirect.com/part-number/9007884/0042/153.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cse&utm_term=9007884&sid=SPDxGPROD&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-5b73aWt1QIVBTBpCh2GkQ5uEAQYAiABEgIDgvD_BwE) with one like this (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0029UK806/ref=asc_df_B0029UK8065097131/?tag=hyprod-20&creative=394997&creativeASIN=B0029UK806&linkCode=df0&hvadid=167149293059&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14507409490979254775&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=t&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9023226&hvtargid=pla-311065465611)?